# What is the difference between an R session, workspace, and image?

Tags: r

There are posts examining the difference between a workspace, environment, image etc. but none comparing these to a RStudio "session".

Comment: Depends on the context in which "session" was used. Also, best not to use R and RStudio interchangeably if we're trying to confirm what terms mean. R is the actual program(s) doing the work, RStudio is just one of several ways to interact with R.

Comment: As I understand it, an "R session" is a running instance of the R program. The user might be using RStudio to interface with it, but not necessarily. The "environment" is the set of objects, packages, and settings which are loaded in a session. The "workspace" is the graphical representation of the environment, ie in RStudio you might have a script window open, an object viewer, the plot window, etc. An "image" could refer to a prepared executable file which encapsulates R and a particular environment so that it can be run in a virtual machine, eg using Docker.